# pgfplots: How to ignore the last line of a data file?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I need to plot data files which contain a comment in the last line, like this:

```
0  2  4
1  5  7
2  9  5  
3 11  15
4 10  15
THIS WAS: TOTAL
```

Now, `pgfplots` seems to have a problem with that giving me an error message complaining about an unbalanced number of columns.

My question is: How do I tell `pgfplots` to ignore the last row of the data file? (I know about the `skip first` option of `pgfplotstable`. Maybe there is an equivalent for the last row that I just couldn't find in the manual.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{total.dos}
0  2  4
1  5  7
2  9  5  
3 11  15
4 10  15
THIS WAS: TOTAL
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{total.dos}\total

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [no markers, red] table [x=0, y=1] {\total}; \addlegendentry{$1$}
\addplot [no markers, blue] table [x=0, y=2] {\total}; \addlegendentry{$2$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is by adding additional line comment characters. For example:

```
\pgfplotstableread[comment chars={T}]{total.dos}\total
```

Will compile properly, i.e. "T" is now considered to start a comment line.

Comment: Nice. Is there also a solution for disallowed words, or a solution that allows you to exclude certain line numbers?

Comment: Particular line numbers are not so simple (as far as I know), although there are other questions knocking around on TeX.sx to do with reading particular lines. The `comment chars` is supposed to be a comma separated list, so I tried `comment chars={THIS}` but LaTeX didn't like it. May be limited to single characters.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about `comment chars`.

Comment: You could also prefix the lines you want ignored with a common comment character, such as `#`. This is pretty easy to do in an editor and leaves letters, such as `T`, free to show up in the data.

Comment: @Sharpie: If this was an option, then Philipp could simply delete those lines. I'm assuming that Philipp needs a semi-automatic way to handle these files, which can't be altered directly.

Comment: @Philipp: You're very welcome. It doesn't seem to be documented, but this optional argument was available for `\pgfplotstabletypeset`, so I tried it and got lucky.